# TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object

Tags: python, unicode, psycopg2

Using this query:

```
04/25/2017 00:42:28.180 INFO (u"UPDATE posts SET translated_text='Unroll.me CEO dice que es &quot;desgarrador&quot; que los usuarios se molesten Unroll.me vendi\xf3 sus datos de correo electr\xf3nico anonimizado a Uber', detected_language='en' WHERE post_id=2", u'Unroll.me CEO dice que es &quot;desgarrador&quot; que los usuarios se molesten Unroll.me vendi\xf3 sus datos de correo electr\xf3nico anonimizado a Uber')
```

With `psycopg2`, when I use: `cur.execute(query)` I get:

```
TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object
```

What is the best option to use query and passing a unicode value. Currently Im already parametrizing the SQL query and passing the 'u'.

```
return u"UPDATE posts SET translated_text='%s', detected_language='%s' WHERE post_id=%s;" % (
        translation, detected_language['language'], str(post_id))
```

I added also without making a difference:

```
import psycopg2.extensions

psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODEARRAY)
```

Comment: Try to use the object string as a `str`, not `unicode` string. So `"UPDATE ..." % (...)` without the initial `u`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That log is showing a **tuple** of unicode strings, rather than a unicode string. Try logging the type of `query` before you execute it to check.

The preferred way to log parameterised query is:

```
query = u"UPDATE posts SET translated_text='%s', detected_language='%s' WHERE post_id=%s;"
vars = translation, detected_language['language'], str(post_id) # tuple
cur.execute(query, vars)
```

You may also wish to explicitly convert the strings of `vars` into unicode rather than relying on this to be done implicitly. eg.

```
vars = translation, detected_language['language'].decode("utf8"), str(post_id).decode("utf8")
```